# Number of operations required for gaussian elimination of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How do I account for (or rather, not account for) the 0's in the matrix so I don't do more operations than necessary? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is linear in time, and consists of two rounds:

1. **forward sweep**, replacing variables by their linear combinations to allow
2. **back substitution** to obtain the final values.

Both steps are linear. Details are on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).